# VBA Code returns error sometimes, and sometimes not

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the code below but I cannot seem to detect what is wrong with it. The program is set to transfer data from workbook:

> SRJem.xlsx

to the active workbook where the code below is written. Now, I have both workbooks open at the same time (and i don't want to close them while doing the operation). The thing is, the code is successful at some time, while it returns a bug error in line 15 in some times. I tried saving both before operation but it still happens.

Line 15:

> ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(14, 1).Value

I need some light explanation regarding the error I have. Thank you so much.

```
Sub transfer_to_masterfile()

'find first empty row in database
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("1")
Dim wbSource As Workbook

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).row + 1

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\fed.staff01\Desktop\J.G.E - QS\6. EXCEL PROGRAMS\SRJem.xlsx") ' <<< path to source workbook

'Now, transfer values from wbSource to wbTarget:
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(14, 1).Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(6, 4).Value

Dim mats As String
Dim row As Integer

row = 23

Do
    mats = mats & "  " & wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(row, 1).Value & "  " & wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(row, 3).Value & _
    "             " & wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(row, 5).Value

    If wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(row + 1, 1).Value > 0 Then
        mats = mats & vbNewLine
    End If

    If wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(row + 1, 1).Value = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    row = row + 1

Loop Until row = 42

ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = mats
'ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = wbSource.Sheets("1").Cells(6, 4).Value

'wbSource.Close
'wbTarget.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Your worksheet is named `"1"`? Or you are trying to refer to the first one `1`?

Comment: @PatricK, i am referring to my Worksheet Name which is "1".

Comment: To mark question as answered, just click that "tick" on the left side of the answer that was helpful to you. [Help file.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many conditions required to avoid the error at the line you mention:

```
1) there must be a file with the name specified for `wbSource`
2) that file must open with an activeSheet named `1`
3) the program workbook (`ws`) must also have a worksheet named `1`
4) there must be a `*` on the activeSheet of the `ws` workbook
```

Notice that there are 2 cases depending on an activeSheet.  To avoid this, I suggest making a variable for each of the sheets you reference (e.g., `set sh = ws.worksheets("1")`) so that you don't depend on that sheet being active or not.  In my experience, that is often the problem, but the other mentioned conditions above could also be the problem.

Comment: thank you for this. I checked my conditions and i dont have problem regarding items 1 to 3. I only have one worksheet in source file and it is named "1". I don't understand item 4 though, sorry. Can you please elaborate this?  I will try your suggestion of having `sh = ws.worksheets("1)` and I will give you feedback.

Comment: Item 4 is based upon your line of code which begins: iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*",... if a * is not found then iRow will be undefined

Comment: I see my error now Sir @Tony M. my iRow will be undefined because I am copying my data on column 4 (column D) instead of Column 1 (column D), therefore, it returns error sometimes. There goes my error. I tried putting any input in first column, and the error is not repeating. I hope I can upvote but I cannot do much but say thank you. ;)

Comment: It's helpful if you can mark your question as answered, if you feel it has been answered

Comment: Noted sir, Thank you.

Comment: @TonyM, the **"*"** is a search wildcard . the search fails on an empty worksheet.  it makes no sense that it fails on line 15. it should be failing at the search line. the only way line 15 will fail, is if the search finds something on the last line of the worksheet, then iRow would be last worksheet line +1, which is a fail